# Fit to extent but with maxResolution

Tags: openlayers, animation

I am using Open Layers 6 and are trying to fit the map to an extent with a smooth animation.

This works fine:

```
 view.fit(extent, {
        easing: easeOut,
        minResolution: 1,
        duration: 1000,
 });
```

BUT I also want to constrain the fit to a maxResolution.

According to the docs there is no maxResolution in the options: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit

So I thought I won't use fit but will use the animate function instead as it offers a few more possibilites:

```
view.animate({
        center: olExtent.getCenter(extent),
        duration: 1000,
        easing: easeOut,
        resolution: getResolution()
})
```

Now I am struggeling to build the `getResolution()` function. Since I cannot find a way to calculate the resolution of an extent *before* it is added to the map. Sth like this does not exist: `olExtent.getResolution(extent)` - or does it?

Comment: Yes, it exists, but it's a view method: `view.getResolutionForExtent(extent, opt_size)`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#getResolutionForExtent

Comment: @TomazicM thanks so much! This is exactly what I was searching for :)